# Non-parametric estimation for irregular functions

Tags: reference-request, st.statistics

I have gone through Tsybakov book "Introduction to Non-Parametric Statistics", this was really instructive. In particular, it adopts a sympathetic minimax approach and gives precise upper bounds and lower bounds for various function estimation problem  : non-parametric regression, density model, Gaussian white noise, ...

But, in all results presented, the functions are supposed to be in a Hölder, Sobolev or Besov space. I wonder if there are any paper with a similar minimax approach tackling more irregular cases ? For example, functions that are only piecewise-Hölder ?

After some quick research, I have found a few papers looking for example at functions exhibiting jumps, but they considered only one dimensional functions and has to suppose a known bound over the number of jumps.